# Azure DevOps: Is it possible it get the source version of all repositories in build?

Tags: github, azure-devops

I have a pipeline and my YAML contains:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: code-repo-1
    type: github
    endpoint: github.com_sa_x
    name: fake-owner/code-repo-1
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)
  - repository: code-repo-2
    type: github
    endpoint: github.com_sa_x
    name: fake-owner/code-repo-2
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)
  - repository: code-repo-3
    type: github
    endpoint: github.com_sa_x
    name: fake-owner/code-repo-3
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)
  - repository: code-repo-4
    type: github
    endpoint: github.com_sa_x
    name: fake-owner/code-repo-4
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)

stages:
  - stage: BuildStage
    displayName: 'Build'
    jobs:
    - job: Maven_build
      steps:
      - checkout: self
        path: s/code-repo-1
      - checkout: code-repo-2
        path: s/code-repo-2
      - checkout: code-repo-3
        path: s/code-repo-3
      - checkout: code-repo-4
        path: s/code-repo-4
```

So I can use `Build.SourceVersion` to get the latest commit ID of the triggering repo that is included in the build.

Is it possible to retrieve the equivalent for the other repos used in this build?

Comment: See [Repository details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-details) and [Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines#variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to retrieve the equivalent for the other repos used in this build?

Yes. To get the latest commit ID of the resource repos, you can use the following format: **resources.repositories.Alias.version**

Here is an example:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: code_repo_1
    type: github
    endpoint: github.com_sa_x
    name: fake-owner/code-repo-1
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)
  - repository: code_repo_2
    type: github
    endpoint: github.com_sa_x
    name: fake-owner/code-repo-2
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)
  - repository: code_repo_3
    type: github
    endpoint: github.com_sa_x
    name: fake-owner/code-repo-3
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)
  - repository: code_repo_4
    type: github
    endpoint: github.com_sa_x
    name: fake-owner/code-repo-4
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranch)

stages:
  - stage: BuildStage
    displayName: 'Build'
    variables:
      commit_code1:  $[ resources.repositories.code_repo_1.version ]
      commit_code2:  $[ resources.repositories.code_repo_2.version ]
      commit_code3:  $[ resources.repositories.code_repo_3.version ]
      commit_code4:  $[ resources.repositories.code_repo_4.version ]
    jobs:
    - job: Maven_build
      steps:
      - checkout: self
        path: s/code-repo-1
      - checkout: code_repo_2
        path: s/code-repo-2
      - checkout: code_repo_3
        path: s/code-repo-3
      - checkout: code_repo_4
        path: s/code-repo-4
      - script: |
         echo $(commit_code1)
         echo $(commit_code2)
         echo $(commit_code3)
         echo $(commit_code4)
```

**Note**: To use the repo Alisa in the Variable, you need to use **_** to replace the **-** in the **repositories -> repository field**.

For example: **- repository: code-repo-1** -> **- repository: code_repo_1**

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Repo resource variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines#variables)

Comment: This looks very promising and close to when I'm looking for. It doesn't seem to be working exactly for me though. I've updated the aliases to `- repository: repo1` for simplicity. Added the following to the BuildStage:     `- script: |
         echo Testing...:
         echo $(Build.SourceVersion)
         echo $(resources.repositories.repo1.version)` and the result is: `5831564a297eebf3c1ef44a35512a7d0ccc6ddf9

/apps/ado/vsts/agent4/_work/_temp/eceada50-917c-492f-9023-285d55a7402b.sh: line 3: resources.repositories.repo1.version: command not found
` Am I doing something silly?

Comment: @Ben you need to map the resource vaiable to pipeline vaiable. then you can use it successfully. please check the sample in the answer.

Comment: this indeed works by assigning to a variable. Disappointing that you can't reference this directly but it is what it is I guess.